# Qemu pci passthrough with a black screen

Tags: debian, virtualization, qemu

I'm currently following this guide https://forum.level1techs.com/t/play-games-in-windows-on-linux-pci-passthrough-quick-guide/108981 to be able to make a vm with a pci passthrough.

My vm is created, and everthing seem ok, but I get a black screen on the second screen (the vm screen) each time.

You can find my virt config file here: https://pastebin.com/RrCuvXg8

lspci -k show that both my video card and audio card (on my video card) are using vfio

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
Kernel modules: radeon
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6450 / 7450/8450/8490 OEM / R5 230/235/235X OEM]
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6450 / 7450/8450/8490 OEM / R5 230/235/235X OEM]
Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

In the /etc/modules file I have everything the tutorial said:

```
vfio
vfio_iommu_type1
vfio_pci
vfio_virqfd
```

And my grub line is set to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intel_iommu=on vfio-pci.ids=1002:6779,1002:aa98 pcie_acs_override=downstream"
```

Is there something I'm missing? If you need more info, I'll edit this post
Thanks

Comment: Do you have **two** different GPUs? The guide states that as one of the requirements. You need two GPUs because you cannot simply "detach" the GPU that your computer is currently using so you need one for the host and one for the guest operating system.

Comment: @Mokubai Like in the guide, I'm using my cpu's gpu (i7-7700k) for the host, and my amd card for the virtual machine